# How do you import lodash into NativeScript Playground

Tags: javascript, lodash, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am learning NativeScript and trying to follow some tutorials while in their Playground and they are using lodash.  According to NativeScripts' blog you should be able to require the lodash module in the playground, using the dropdown. (https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-playground-is-on-fire)

[image]
[image]

This works and the lodash folder is added in the app folder.  The problem occurs when I try to import it.  It says lodash is not found.  I have tried:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import _ from 'lodash';
var _ = require ('lodash');
```

And many other suggestions, but none of these seem to work.  I have tried add the @types (which NativeScript says they add automatically), but it fails even with the @types/lodash added.

[image]

Anyone know how to make this work in NativeScript playground?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple require statement with relative path.

```
const _ = require('../lodash');
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but wouldn't that the same as `var _ = require('../lodash');` other than defining it as a constant instead of a variable.  It doesn't work... Fresh playground, loaded the npm lodash module, added require statement with correct path, and fails.... and the @type/lodash and it still fails... using NS+Angular.

Comment: Hold on... my preview app was stuck on the wrong project even after updating the QR Code many times... grrr... `const _ = require('../lodash');` && `var _ = require('../lodash');` both work and no need to import @types . Thanks.

Comment: For anyone experiencing the issues with the preview app showing the wrong app, go here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=3p3qsa scan the QR Code. It will cause an error but won't crash the preview app.  Then rescan your projects QR Code and wait a few seconds for it to update.... To find out more about this limitation, please read... https://github.com/NativeScript/playground-feedback/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

Probably in newer versions of NativeScript I would first suggest to review your `node_modules` directory as in my case `lodash` is already there.

And if this is the case for you as well, you just need to use it w/o installing anything

```
# home.component.ts
import { shuffle } from 'lodash';
```